# Arduino board with built-in Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to find an Arduino with built-in Bluetooth. 
I know about the HC-06, the shields and the other Bluetooth modules, but i would like to have built in Bluetooth for eliminating the risk for miscommunication on the serial port.

The official Arduino foundation did produce an board but it's retired now.

Comment: Wow! Look what I found on [GOOGLE!](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=arduino+board+with+built+in+bluetooth&tbm=shop&*) :)

Comment: By the way, how could miscommunication on a Bluetooth shield be any different from miscommunication on an integrated Bluetooth for a board?

Comment: Yeah i know what google is. Why it would be better? Less moving parts, well tested board. If you think its an dumb question dont answer then. There are plenty of other post waiting for your knowledge.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic, but have you thought this through?  I appreciate that there might be an issue with serial comms, but I would have thought most of that would be programming errors rather than a 'hardware' issue.  If I'm not right say!  Having a separate board would give you the advantage of being able to spare it or upgrade it to support BT5, BT6 or even BT 921!  Also a separate board means you have more options over what the Arduino board can be.  Maybe looking at why you have serial problems would be a good point to focus on?

Comment: @Sigma - If a board becomes a moving part, you need to check your soldering :D

Comment: Yeah you are probable right. But when the application iworks 98% of the time. It makes it hard to understand or debugg what the 2% failures are because of. I need to be 100% sure it is programmatic and not hardware.

Comment: @Sigma Well I don't think it's a dumb question. Perfectly reasonable to ask something that you're not sure of. I was just curious on why you weren't looking for a shield instead but that's good reason :)

Comment: As far as officially Arduino boards with Bluetooth, I can't think of any on the top of my head. Then again, I'm not entirely sure if Adafruit (for an example) would consider themselves to be an official Arduino brand, though I doubt it.

Comment: Adafruit could be a good place to look. Thanks! Have seen that there has been some kickstarter boards, but they are not mass produced.

Comment: What about using an ESP32 with integrated BT?

Comment: @CodeGorilla Yeah that could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino has just released a **MKR WIFI 1010** board that includes an *ESP32* module that allows Bluetooth connectivity. It's mainly an internet of things board but it supports:

- Bluetooth low energy, BLE
- Wifi

[image: Arduino MKR Wifi 1010]

Comment: Yes Im using that one, great board.

Answer (score 1):

There is this board called Bluno
Its an Arduino UNO Based board with built in Bluetooth 4.0

[Bluno - An Arduino Bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) Board](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1044.html)

[image: Bluno - An Arduino Bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) Board]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my currently favourite Arduino compatible board:
https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d32:d32

[image]

ESP32 is great: offers both wi-fi, Bluetooth and BLE connection as well as lots of GPIO. 
9 GPIO's can be used as capacitive touch sensors (it has 10, but only 9 are available).

Comment: This is also a great option.